# Appending an empty list to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, web-scraping

I am looping through a soup and would like to add elements to a dictionary. As of now my code looks like this:

```
  dict1 = {"Film Director: ":[], "Film Producer: ":[], "Film cast: ":[]}
  info = soup2.find("table", class_="something")
  for tr in info.find_all("tr"):
      columns = tr.find_all("td")[0].text
      values = tr.find_all("td")[1].text
      dict1[columns].append([values])
```

The problem is that some sites contain more info than others whereby an output can be somethin like this

```
{'Film Director: ': [['tom'], ['phil'], ['daniel']], 'Film Producer: ': [['mike'], ['kay'], ['banks']], 'Film cast: ': [['luke, shadraa, shwarma'], ['mohammed, abdul, sarkis']]}
```

How do I also add an empty list to the film cast key? I want this so that I will be able to create an accurate dataframe later.

Comment: dict1["film cast"] = []   is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Use `extend`

```
dict1[columns].extend([values])
```

so you will not have nested lists

Comment: This is not the problem, the problem is that some keys have 3 values, while some have 2.

Comment: So you advice to initialize list just to call `list.extend()` instead of calling proper function which is `list.append()`?